# Send animated gif to Telegram in Dialogflow

Tags: telegram, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to send gifs as response in my chatbot in Dialogflow.
Actually, I send the url by *Custom payload* 
This is the Json response:

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "text": "[alt](path/dog.gif).",
    "parse_mode": "Markdown"
   }
}
```

But in Telegram looks like other link (user can see the path of the gif above ). 
Exists other way? I've tried with a Webhook in nodejs too but not success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sendDocument` method for sending `GIF` file.

use the `document` parameter for your GIF file.

Comment: Thanks, so.. the sendDocument is avaible from Dialogflow console? (i thought that was neccesary the Telegram API)